# Custom directive inside ng-repeat shows different result of when i use it out of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Custom directive inside ng-repeat showing not expected result

I have created directive which can accept different value i call it and its working fin, but when i use this directive inside ng-repeat its showing same result for each iteration

here is the directive :

```
.directive("rating", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.flavor = $attrs.value;
            $scope.getStars = function () {
                var size = $scope.flavor / 5 * 100;
                return size;
            }
        },
        template: '<span ng-bind="getStars()"></span>'
    }
});
```

when i call it in this way its work fine and its show the expected result

```
<rating value="1"></rating> // <span>20</span>
<rating value="2"></rating> // <span>40</span>
<rating value="3"></rating> // <span>60</span>
```

but when i use it inside ng-repeat its show same result for each iteration even the value is different because its coming from $index.

```
<div ng-repeat="review in vm.reviews">
    <rating value="{{$index+1}}"></rating>  
</div>
// <span>20</span>
// <span>20</span>
// <span>20</span>
```

i expect the result to be

```
// <span>20</span>
// <span>40</span>
// <span>60</span>
```

i think the issue in $scope.flavor there should be way to force it to be updated with each iteration

Comment: ```templateUrl``` is wrong, should be ```template``` if you pass some HTML and not an URL. Besides, if you pass values 1, 2, 3 getStars returns 20, 40, 60 and not your expected result. Do you have some fiddle to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in my [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/qHTwFd4FCQPNkF4l9HwE?p=preview). So there is something behind the scene you're doing wrong.

But actually I would do this in another way. You don't need to wrap `value=` attribute in `{{}}` if you pass something into directive's `$scope`. Just make your `directive`'s `$scope` isolated and explicitly specify that `value` is an expression (`'<'` or `'='`).

```
scope: {
  value: '<'
}
```

And then you can reach it via `$scope.value` in your `link` function. Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dPwLEHdS33tZZ0EDdLWO?p=preview) too.